# how to add actionbarsherlok to a project on android studio for mac?

Tags: java, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

my android project uses `actionbarsherlok`, and I'm struggling on how to satisfy this dependency on `android studio`. In the tutorial on how to install actionbarsherlok is not explicitly explained for android studio.

I searched my mac for the program `ant` and `android`, but could not find anything... any idea?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add it to your dependencies in your **build.gradle** the following lines:

```
dependencies {

     compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

     ... other dependencies

}
```

Comment: I don't have a `build.gradle`. I have a `project.properties`... I guess this is similar.

Comment: Are you switching to Android Studio from Eclipse? If you have a look at the documentation there's a function in Eclipse in order to have a project that follows the structure for gradle build based ones. Otherwise I don't get the point in using Android Studio if you are not going to take advantage of the build features of Gradle.

Comment: from AS 0.4.3 you can not even import eclipse projects without gradle build system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I do now understand more deeply the point. Now I see, thank to your help, that this question is indeed "not relevant" and obsolete.